# Correct or proper usage of "I" v. "we"

Tags: grammar

Would it be proper to say "Here is a picture of my cousins and I".  Is it improper to say me instead of I?

Comment: I'd never use 'I' here. The preposition 'of' takes the accusative case, no matter how many elements there are in the prepositional object. There is a move towards the use of 'of/from X and I', but it's a hypercorrection.

Comment: IF you're a native speaker of English, it should sound wrong to you. If you've been told otherwise, distrust grammar advice from that person from now on; either they're putting you on or they're very confused about English grammar.

Comment: The use of "me" in this context pre-supposes the importance of the self.  "I" is much preferred since it puts the weight of the sentence on the *other*, in this case your cousins.  Perhaps this question might be better answered on http://philosophy.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Simple practical rule of thumb: Drop the other subject for a moment. Which sounds right: "Here is a picture of I", or "Here is a picture of me"?

The same answer applies when the other subject is added back in.

(For comparison, consider "My friends and I went to the beach.")

Comment: There might well be people who consider *Here is a picture of I* to be correct. The "which sounds right rule/trick" does not always help learners of English.

Comment: Granted, @Mari-LouA. But it's a way to simplify the problem into a more general one.